# sum of all drop down values

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I have a dropdown in my jsp with all users from database. When I select a user I'm able to get the details of the corresponding result, but when I click on all it should give the total individually.  Below is the code that I use to get individually.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head> 
    <body><form name="Reports" method="post" action="DropDown.jsp"><table><tr>

                     <td>From</td><td><input type="text" id="from" name="from"></td></tr>

                     <tr><td>To</td><td><input type="text" id="to" name="to"></td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Select user:</td><td><select name="user" id="user">


            <option value="">Select User</option>
            <%
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement("select substr(sys_connect_by_path(userid,','),2) userid from (select rownum rowno,'''' || userid || '''' userid from users where rownum < 4)where connect_by_isleaf = 1 connect by prior rowno = rowno - 1 start with rowno = 1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
              %>
                <option value="<%String user2=rs.getString(1);out.println(user2);%>">All</option>
                <%
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                                       {
                out.println(e);
            }
            %>
            <%
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement("Select Distinct Specialist from Scope1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
              %>
                <option value="'<%String user1=rs.getString(1);out.print(user1);%>'"><%out.print(user1);%></option>
                <%
            }
            out.println("<select>");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                                       {
                out.println(e);
            }
            %>

                             </select></td></tr>
                     <tr><td>
        Select Type:</td><td><select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="">Select Type</option>
            <option value="'Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll'">All</option>
            <%
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement("Select Distinct type from Scope1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
        %>
                <option value="'<%String type1=rs.getString(1).trim();out.print(type1);%>'"><%out.println(type1.trim());%></option>
                <%
            }
            out.println("<Select>");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                                       {
                out.println(e);
            }
            %>
                            </select></td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Generate" id="sub1" name="sub1"></td></tr>
        </table> </form>   </body>
</html>
```

and the get result is as below.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body><table>
        <%
        String a=request.getParameter("type").trim();
        String b=request.getParameter("user").trim();
        String c=request.getParameter("from").trim();
        String d=request.getParameter("to").trim();
        try{%>
        <tr><b><%=b%></b></tr><%
            //String sql=("SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ("+a+") and Specialist in ("+b+") and (RECVD_DATE >='"+c+"' and RECVD_DATE <='"+d+"') group by type");
            //out.print(sql);
            ps1=con.prepareStatement("SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ("+a+") and Specialist in ("+b+") and (RECVD_DATE >='"+c+"' and RECVD_DATE <='"+d+"') group by type");
            rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next())
            {
            %>

            <tr><td><b><%=rs1.getString(1)%></b></td><td><%=rs1.getString(2)%></td></tr>
            <%
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e);
}
%>
   </table> </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you have a sizable SQL injection issue to address

Comment: means? sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: Have a quick read of https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Parameterized_Queries to see what @BrianAgnew is getting at.

Comment: OK thank you David and Brain. i got it. i'll change the code, but , how do i solve the problem that i mentioned above?